# Given the sequence $a_1=6$ and $a_{n+1}=3a_n-8$ when $n\ge2$.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Given the sequence $a_1=6$ and $a_{n+1}=3a_n-8$ when $n\ge2$. Show that the sequence with common term $b_n=a_n-4$ is a GP. Find the general term of $\{a_n\}$.

We know that $b_n$ will be a GP if $b_n=b_{n-1}q$ for all $n\ge2$. Is $b_{n+1}=b_nq$ for all $n\ge1$ the same thing and why (I mean are the conditions equivalent for the sequence to be a GP?)?

In other words, we need the ratio $\dfrac{b_{n+1}}{b_n}=q$ (or $\frac{b_n}{b_{n-1}}$) to be a constant for all $n\ge1$.

In our problem $b_{n+1}=a_{n+1}-4=3a_n-12$ and $\dfrac{b_{n+1}}{b_n}=\dfrac{3(a_n-4)}{a_n-4}=3\quad\quad\forall n\ge1$

Are these thoughts enough for us to conclude that the sequence with common term $b_n=a_n-4$ is a geometric progresion? Can you clarify the method for me a little?

How am I supposed to find the general term $a_n$?

Comment: You showed $\frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n}=q=\mathrm{const}$ for every $n\geq 1$. Then by definition sequence $(b_n)$ is a geometric progression. In order to find the general term $a_n$ you can use $b_n=a_n-4$. Can you find the general term $b_n$?